# Command find show "Value too large for defined data type"

Tags: linux, nfs, mount, find, unmount

When I run the "find" command in any folder, works perfect, but only in a particular folder I get this:

root#find

.
find:.: Value too large for defined data type

It is a shared folder from another server nfs. With umount and mount not change anything. This worked before, but not now. A That is because the "Value too large for defined data type"

Comment: What distro and architecture is this ?

Comment: [root@server prueba]#uname -a

Linux server 2.6.9-5.ELsmp #1 SMP Wed Jan 5 19:30:39 EST 2005 

i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

[root@server prueba]#lsb_release -a

LSB Version:    1.3

Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseAS

Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant)

Release:        4

Codename:       Nahant

[root@server prueba]#

Comment: Seems a known bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=141167

Answer (score 1):

Your ancient OS is 32bit something being returned to it is too large for a 32bit value. There is more about the general problem -[here](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html#Value-too-large-for-defined-data-type).

There is an equally ancient [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=141167) which suggests that the problem is intermittent and suggests downgrading to an earlier version of findutils ([findutils-4.1.7-25](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/18729136/dir/fedora_2/com/findutils-4.1.7-25.i386.rpm.html))- although I wouldn't want to go making changes to that system as it may make it worse.

Your OS is over a decade old - it's probably a good idea to see about bringing it up-to-date.

Comment: I understand what you say, but in empty subfolders also shows me the error in a directory structure /folder1/folder2/empty_folder.
Why it shows me the same error in the empty folder?
And higher folders shows me the contents of subfolders without error.

Answer (score 0):

NFS version 3 may give such kind of errors on old systems.
try to mount the same NFS with version 2:

```
mount -F NFS -o vers=2 200.19.19.19:sharedfact /mnt/thefact
```